# Solr search Query with white spaces or without case sensitive and exact matching

Tags: solr

I am implementing the solr for searching product but its not working in some case.
for example:

> productcode=030101 01

in schema.xml i used

```
<fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/> 

<field name="itemcode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

if i changed fieldtype i.e

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
                maxPosAsterisk="2" maxPosQuestion="1" minTrailing="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

 <field name="itemcode" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
```

then its searching productcode=030101 01 but its also searching

```
030101 02
030101 03
030101 04
```

now exact searching not working. as i have some product code which have lowercase and uppercase character then it also creating problem in search.

Thanks in advance for your time.
ashu

Answer (score 0):

If you only need lowercase & exact search, can you remove 'WhitespaceTokenizerFactory' & 'ReversedWildcardFilterFactory' during index & query for fieldType=text_ws?

Also look at "solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"